# Are there any multipolygons in my shapefile?

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry

In QGIS 2.x, is there a simple way to determine if a polygons layer contains multipolygon geometries and if yes: which are these features?

Answer (score 10):

The [Topology Checker plugin](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html) has an option to check if a layer contains multipart geometries.

[image]

It is also possible to highlight multipart geometries.

Answer (score 5):

Not tested but perhaps use something like this in the **Python Console**:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
geom = QgsGeometry()
if layer.wkbType() == QGis.WKBMultiPolygon:
    for feature in layer.getFeatures(): 
        if geom.isMultipart():
            print feature.id()
```